# Cloudinary and Rails: undefined method `upload' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloudinary

I am working on a Rails app, but I am running into issues with Cloudinary for image upload.  My other apps have used Cloudinary with no problem, so I am not sure what is causing the error.

I put the :photo in the model, updated the controller params, and set development and production storage to :cloudinary.  However, I am noticing the images actually aren't being uploaded to my Cloudinary account.

Once I'm brought to the Show page, I get hit with this error:

undefined method `upload' for nil:NilClass with the if@pin.save line highlighted

```
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: "Pin created!"
    else
      render 'new'
```

My Pins get created once I go back to the index, but when I click on it I get undefined method for photo.

Here is my show page code:

```
<h1><%= @pin.title %></h1>
<p><%= @pin.description %></p>
<p> Submitted by <%= @pin.user.email %></p>

<br>
<%= link_to "Back", root_path %>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_pin_path %>
<%= link_to "Delete", pin_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Invariably, "undefined method `upload' for nil:NilClass" means you forgot to define something or mistyped it.

Comment: I have nothing called Upload though.  And for the error log it only shows the Create part of my Pins Controller.

Comment: What version of the Cloudinary gem are you running and is it the same across the other projects?

Comment: I am running 'cloudinary', '~> 1.12.0'.  I've done the same thing each time.  When I try to create a pin with a picture, I get an undefined method error for 'upload' which I never made.  If I go back to the index and check the pin, I get an undefined error message for cl_image_tag.

Comment: It sounds like the gem is not accessible in your code. Any chance it was installed in a different ruby environment to the one the code runs on?

Comment: I fixed it.  Stupid solution, but I just needed to restart the Rails server.  Thanks for your help.